# gson version conflict & unable resolve com.google.gson/2.8.6 missing requirement [com.google.gson/2.8.6] osgi.ee filter:=&osgi.ee=JavaSE version=9.0

Tags: java, gson, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have some xyz existing pkg which use google.gson version 2.2.4.

I am creating new pkg(osgi bundle) for http client to call api, I need gson version 2.8.6.

If I go with existing version i.e. 2.2.4, I get following below issue during compilation.

Conflict(s) found for the following module(s):
- com.google.code.gson:gson between versions 2.9.0 and 2.8.6

And if I go with version i.e. 2.8.6, which is required in my case, existing test fails -
This is the actual error behind the integrationtest failure  :
-Unable to resolve com.google.gson/2.8.6: missing requirement [com.google.gson/2.8.6] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=9.0))

java java version "1.8.0_311" with Gradle 5.2

Answer (score 0):

The error messages `missing requirement [com.google.gson/2.8.6] osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=9.0))` means that version 2.8.6 requires at least Java 9.